# Cascading of Lookup Dropdown Fields with multi parent column on SharePoint 2013 and Office 365

Tags: sharepoint-online

I need to do one more filter(relationshipListParentColumn)along with Company column. In employee list, Company and Designation columns are there. I need to use both these columns to filter EmpName. I tried but unable to filter. Can you help to achieve this. Thanks

CODE:

```
<script src="https://site name/jquery.min.js"></script>  
<script src="https://sitename/jquery.SPServices.min.js"></script>  
<script type="text/javascript">  
$(document).ready(function ()  
{  
    $().SPServices.SPCascadeDropdowns(  
    {  
        relationshipList: "Employee",  
        relationshipListParentColumn: "Company",  
        relationshipListChildColumn: "EmpName",  
        parentColumn: "Company",  
        childColumn: "Employee",  
        debug: true  
    });  
});  
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can take advantage of SharePoint REST API to do such task. Just call the following end point using ajax.

`//site_url/_api/web/lists/getByTitle('Title of List')/Items?$filter=Company eq 'Comany Name' and Designation eq 'designation'&$select=EmpName`.

This will give you the list of EmployeeName in JSON object. Just bind that object to you Employee column.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I tried to achieve as you mentioned but not successful. I am new to development. Can you please help to achieve this.

Comment: Are you able to call the REST endpoint? What response you are getting. Also what is the type of column for company and designation.